# Express server problem when try to setHeader

Tags: node.js, express

I have created a express server and send response with headers.

When I try to fetch that in frontend browser dev tool show my header which I created but when I try to get the header in code give me undefined and show empty header
I spent much time to fix it , but I can't please help me

How I can fix it please help me

Comment: Remember to [show your code](/help/how-to-ask) (in [mcve] form). You've described the problem, but only your code can show folks what you're actually doing wrong.

Comment: without the code is pretty impossibile to give you assistance, as already pointed by @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans